# what is difference between foo=bar(foo) and something=bar(foo) in decorator in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

I read about we can create reference of any function in python but i also read that while creating a decorator we use a special syntax called "@" : ex:  @decorator_function 
 and this `@decorator_function` is equal to `new_function=decorator_function(new_function)`

so my doubt is in my view both :

1. `anything = decorator_function(new_function)`
2. `new_function=decorator_function(new_function)`

both are playing the role of closure but both result different output. so what is big difference between both of them?

example code :

```
def deco(fn):
    def wrapper(*args):
        print('called')
        return fn(*args)

    return wrapper


def something(x):
    if x == 0:
        print('first')
        something(x+1)
    else:
        print('hello')


print('new name')
a = deco(something)
a(0)
print('\nreassigning to the same name')
something = deco(something)
something(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, `a = deco(something)`

```
def deco(fn):
    def wrapper(*args):
        print('called') 
        return something(*args)      # Notice here
return wrapper
```

The second one, `something = deco(something)` is just the same *except* your original function `something` now has become the `wrapper` function that `deco` returned.

```
>>> something
<function deco.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fbae4622f28>
>>> a
<function deco.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fbae4622ea0>
```

Both `something` and `a` wrap the *original* `something` before it was overridden by `something = deco(something)` assignment. Python internally stored the original `something` function somewhere in the wrapper functions:

```
>>> something.__closure__[0].cell_contents
<function something at 0x7fbae4622bf8>

>>> a.__closure__[0].cell_contents
<function something at 0x7fbae4622bf8>
```

In the last assignment `something` has become something different:

```
>>> something
<function deco.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fbae4622f28>
```

Answer (score 4):

The original `something` function you wrote makes a recursive call to `something`, not `a`.

If you assign `deco(something)` to `a`, then `something` is still the original function, and the recursive call will call the original function:

- new function calls original function
- original function looks up `something`, finds original function
- original function calls original function...

If you assign `deco(something)` to `something`, then `something` is now the new function, and the recursive call will call the new function:

- new function calls original function
- original function looks up `something`, finds new function
- original function calls new function
- new function calls original function...

Comment: What do you mean by new function in second paragraph ?

Comment: @Elanaunderhill: The function created and returned by `deco`.

Comment: It would be better explain with example ?

Comment: @user2357112 in the second p you are overwriting the function `something` in with the call `something = deco(something)`. The initial `something` function will never be called again.

Comment: @DanielF: It will, because the new function calls the original.

Comment: And please also explain why its happen ?

Comment: Oh, I see, what an interesting situation.

Comment: Speak in terms of objects. You define an object `def something` and refer to that object inside that function (recurse). In that recursion you no longer refer to the name of the function `something`, but to the object. In `something = deco(something)` you wrap the `something` function object into another function object which `deco` returns, but you then rename this object to `something`, so that all new future references to `something` refer to this wrapper object while the old `something` inside the wrapper still refers to the old `something` object.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your assignments using manual calls to the decorator work. But one of them (the one that rebinds `something`) replaces the original function so that it can't be reached by its original name any more. It's not any different than using any other assignment. For instance:

```
def foo(x):
    return x + 1

a = 10

a = foo(a)
```

When you assign the result of `foo(a)` to `a`, it replaces the old value of `10` with a new value `11`. You can't get the `10` any more.

Decorator syntax does the same thing.

```
def deco(fn):
    def wrapper(*args):
        print('called')
        return fn(*args)

    return wrapper

def func_1(x):
    pass
func_1 = deco(func_1) # replace the old func_1 with a decorated version

@deco                 # the @ syntax does the same thing!
def func_2(x):
    pass
```

It's not forbidden to use a decorator to create a differently named function, it's just not normally as useful (and so there's no special syntax for it):

```
def func_3(x):
    pass

func_4 = deco(func_3) # this works, creating a new function name without hiding the old one
```